# Uninstalling Twitter Bootstrap from a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I recently installed Twitter Bootstrap in my Rails app via the following two steps:

```
rails g bootstrap:install
```

(this included Twitter Bootstrap to my app's asset pipeline)

```
rails g bootstrap:layout application fixed
```

(this generated a layout for me, by default `application.html.erb` and fixed layout was generated)

Should I do any of the following or all of it to remove Twitter Bootstrap completely from my app?

1. Delete all the files added by it in APP folder?

   - `javascripts/bootstrap.js.coffee`
   - `stylesheets/bootstrap.js.coffee`
   - `layout/application.html.erb` (edit this file?)
2. Are there other files that were created that I missed and must also remove?

Comment: Are you using version control (e.g. Git)? If not you definitely should be, if you were this could be as simply as reverting a commit.

Comment: I am using git and github but since adding Twitter Bootstrap I've made significant changes, can I still revert a specific commit from long time ago?

Comment: You can, but there may be merge conflicts that you'll have to resolve. Just look up reverting a commit and resolving merge conflicts and give it a try!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the github repo for this you can see the generators and what exactly they do:

https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/tree/master/lib/generators/bootstrap

The command

```
rails g bootstrap:install
```

Uses the templates here:
https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/tree/master/lib/generators/bootstrap/install/templates

The layout command  uses the templates here:
https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/tree/master/lib/generators/bootstrap/layout/templates

Also, remove the gem from your gemfile

```
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
```

Comment: Thanks so much this was the exact explanation I needed!

Answer (score 17):

Try this

```
rails destroy bootstrap:install
```

Also, remove the gem from your gemfile

`gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"`

Comment: Doesn't work I've the following error message:
Could not find generator 'bootstrap:install'